# run npm postinstall only once

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to run the postinstall script of npm only once (after you first `npm install` with no arguments)

I tried looking at the docs but couldn't find anything. Any idea on how to do this (other than saving a local file the first time you run the post-install?)

Comment: What's wrong with this approach. I mean the saving of a local file and checking if it is there during the next install.

Comment: I was just wondering if npm provides a proper way of doing this that's all. The method of saving a file to disk is not as intuitive as an npm provided solution that would be in your package.json that's all

Comment: Aham, I understand. I personally don't know any other method.

Answer (score 0):

To add any kind of logic to an npm handler I usually execute a js script and I write all the logic inside that. If your postinstall function does some changes in files you can check with your js script if those changes are been made, understanding this way if this is the first time npm install was executed or not. If not your js script will continue to execute postinstall tasks.